# upper bound for the maximum value of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z^3e^{z^2}-e^{3z^2}$. Are the following arguments valid?

For $R>0$,
$$\begin{align*}
\max_{z\in\bar{B(0,R)}}|f(z)| &\le|R^3e^{R^2}-e^{3R^2}|\\
&\le |R^3e^{R^2}|\end{align*}$$

since $e^{3R^2}>0$.

Comment: No, because $z$ is a complex number the first line won't hold

Comment: so what would be a possible estimate (for the first line)?

Comment: I don't see anything immediately useful other than the maximum modulus principle

Comment: what do you mean? if i use the maximum modulus principle to f(z), i will have that the maximum must be less than or equal to the value of f in the boundary, which is?

Answer (score 1):

Using the triangle inequality, 
$$|z^3 e^{z^2}-e^{3z^2}|\le |z^3 e^{z^2}| + |e^{3z^2}| 
= |z|^3 e^{\operatorname{Re} (z^2)}+ e^{ 3\operatorname{Re} (z^2)}$$
When $|z|\le R$, we can estimate the above by 
$$R^3 e^{R^2} + e^{3R^2}$$
By the way, the second term here is much larger than the first, when $R$ is large.

And the estimate is in fact the best possible, because 
$$|f(-R)| = |-R^3 e^{R^2}-e^{3R^2}| = R^3 e^{R^2} + e^{3R^2}$$